# Partial derivative implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

dz/dx = ?

cos(zy)+zx^2 = (1+y)e^(x-z)

For the left side through implicit differentiation I have found (-sin(zy))(y*(dz/dx))+2xz+(dz/dx)x^2. I am completely unsure how to approach the right side, however.

Comment: i guess it will $1 + y$ will just be treated like a constant and then you do compodition on $e^{x-z}$ leaving $-(1+y)\frac{dz}{dx}e^{x-z}$, but im not totaly sure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is quite simple if you use [the implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Consider the implicit function
$$F=\cos (y z)+x^2 z-(y+1) e^{x-z}\color{red}{=0}$$ Then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=2 x z-(y+1) e^{x-z}$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=x^2+(y+1) e^{x-z}-y \sin (y z)$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} } {\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} }=\frac{(y+1) e^{x-z}-2 x z}{x^2+(y+1) e^{x-z}-y \sin (y z)}$$